# MVVMcross upgrade from 4 to 6.2.1 getting error Mvx does not contain definition of Close Trace Error , warning etc

Tags: mvvmcross

after upgrade on mvvmcross 6.2.1 getting error Mvx does not contain definition 
     of Traces , Warning , Error, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot have changed since Mvx 4. You should read the [documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/), [blogs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/blog/) and migration guides ([from 4 to 5](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-50?scroll=2224), [from 5 to 6](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60)).

About traces, warning, error, now Mvx has a new way you can do [Diagnostic & Logging](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging). You have to inject/resolve `IMvxLog` and there you will have all the methods to do trace, warning, error, etc.

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxLog _log;
    public MyViewModel(IMvxLog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        _log.Trace("Some message");
    }
}
```

In order to close a viewmodel you need to use the new [Navigation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation) system:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        // first callback. Initialize parameter-agnostic stuff here
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();

        // do the heavy work here
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var result = await _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel, MyObject, MyReturnObject>(new MyObject());
        //Do something with the result MyReturnObject that you get back
    }
}

public class NextViewModel : MvxViewModel<MyObject, MyReturnObject>
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    private MyObject _myObject;

    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        // first callback. Initialize parameter-agnostic stuff here
    }

    public override void Prepare(MyObject parameter)
    {
        // receive and store the parameter here
        _myObject = parameter;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
    }

    public async Task SomeMethodToClose()
    {
        await _navigationService.Close(this, new MyReturnObject());
    }
}
```

If you want to return nothing just do `_navigationService.Close(this)` (of course you have to remove the generic type parameter of `MyReturnObject` in order to do so) and that's it.

HIH

Comment: For trace and error working your andswer is correct but does not supports warning.  Furnter more i have lot of error after upgrade doesnot supports thuis command Close(this);                                                                                                            
   and this not implemented                               
  base.ShowViewModel<T>(parameterValuesObject); any further suggestions

Comment: Yes, it does for warning you use `_log.Warn("whatever you want to warn about");`. 
I'll update for closing but please go to the links and read the documentation because a lot has changed

Comment: I am waiting the update for Close but i am getting this also how it is resolved  'MvxViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ShowViewModel'

Comment: You haven't even peaked the documentation... Please read it and you'll find out how to do all the changes. It is very clear.
If you find a particular problem that you don't understand ask another question with your attempt to do what you want to achieve, but please do not start a thread asking every error it gives you without even reading the docs about the changes in the Mvx versions